# How to update widgets when a route resumes?

Tags: flutter

Is there any equivalent for Android Acyivity's "onResume" in flutter? I want to refresh a widget in a previous route when Navigator pops a route and comes back to previous route. WidgetBingingObserver only works when app is resumed from background not when a route is resumed.

Answer (score 2):

When you push to new page, you will get the `Future` which will get resolved on pop.

```
 var future = Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
        );
 future.then((value) {
         print(value);
         print("popeed");
        });
```

You can send values from nextPage like (It is optional, if you are not sending it will be null while resolving future)

```
Navigator.pop(context, 2);
```

Comment: This works of course but I was thinking there should be another way to do stuff when a route is resumed to foreground.

Comment: Thank you! I needed this

Comment: If the `navigator` replaces `SecondScreen` to another route, like using `pushReplacementNamed` method, the `future` will be returned when the replacement happens.